# .Net Core 2.0 React VS template import component is invalid to render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a web project using **default** `.Net Core 2.0` `React` web template in Visual Studio 2017. And then installed [ReactTable](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) using `npm install -save react-table @types/react-table`. Everything works fine.

Then I wanted to use the component. So inside `ClientApp/components/FetchData.tsx` file, at the top

`import { ReactTable } from 'react-table';`

Then I replaced `renderForecastsTable` with

```
const columns = [
    {
        Header: 'Date formatted',
        accessor: 'dateFormatted'
    }, {
        Header: 'Summary',
        accessor: 'summary'
    }
];

return <ReactTable data={forecasts} columns={columns} />;
```

When I run in Chrome, the following error happens: `vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:118 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of FetchData.`

I guess this is due to some setting in web pack or project is missing, so that it can't find the component during run time. Any idea?

**Edit** `Webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

Comment: Could you try this. Keep in mind that this is not a best solution if it works out for you.`var ReactTable = require("react-table").default;`

Comment: No, `react-table` doesn't have a default defined.

Comment: And w/o default ?

Comment: `TS2604: JSX element type 'ReactTable' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: Could you post your webpack config file?

Comment: Sure. I didn't modify anything came with the VS template

Comment: Well this is very strange. I have never tried it with the VS template but I had it working with js/ts. BTW. It would be much better to use js instead of ts it will save you some time cuz I had a lot of trouble with type script in the end switched to js. If I find something I'll let you know. Meanwhile if u don't have any dependencies just switch to js.

Answer (score 0):

Try use import ReactTable from 'react-table'

Comment: There's no default export, so `TS1192: Module "node_modules/@types/react-table/index"' has no default export.` error.